# problem to uppercase some Turkish characters as "i" to "İ" in R studio

Tags: r, encoding, uppercase, toupper

When I make "İzmir" uppercase it becomes "İZMIR".
I need it to be "İZMİR"

I use UTF-8 encoding for a column as Encoding(dt[[4]]) <- "UTF-8"
I observed the problem occurs with "i"
I need your help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Is R running on Macbook? If answer is yes, open terminal and copy this code:

```
defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8
```

paste then run. Let me know if it works.